# WP Custom page template not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to put custom design to my login page and for this I am using WP page template. Following is the code sample

```
<?php
/**
   Template Name: Fresh Login Page
*/
?>
<!-- Here my new HTML structure for login page. -->
```

Then from page setting I have set(apply) "Fresh Login Page" as a dropdown value under section "Page" Attributes. 
But no luck in front end. Default content is still there. 
Also I am using "iMember360", "optimizepress" frameworks in my WP installation, not sure if these plugin break this process.

Comment: Sounds like cache is hindering your development. Can you check all plugins etc for caching and flush their cache if possible

Comment: Don't have any cache plugin installed

Comment: Could it be browser cache then? The fact that WP let's you choose it in the administration of a page is confirmation that it is usable. Maybe http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens can help you

Comment: Tried in different browsers by delete cookies, cache etc. Also tried in Private browser. These things first I check after making any updates.

Comment: It could be either one of those plugins effecting it, they both make a lot of alterations. Your hosting might also have some kind of cache going, might want to check into that.